# how to install iOS 5 on iPhone with iOS 5 beta installed

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a beta version of iOS 5 installed on my iPhone. I don't remember which beta but version in About on iPhone says it is iOS 5 (9A5313e). I already replaced iTunes 10.5 beta with iTunes 10.5 (141) that is the recent version on the apple site. When I press "Check for Updates" it says: "This version of the iPhone software (5.0) is the current version.". When I press "Restore" it says: "There was a problem downloading the software for iPhone. The requested resource was not found". I have no other ideas what to do.

Comment: This belongs on http://superuser.com  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: With respect, I disagree - this question is unique to developers with access to the beta updates and does seem to fall under: "software tools commonly used by programmers" and
"practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession". Non-programmers don't (or shouldn't) have access to the betas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the ios image from the apple dev center.

Then, hold down Option, and click "Restore" (in itunes with the device you want to upgrade selected).  Then select the beta ios image file you downloaded when the file prompt shows up, and click "ok".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to install non-beta. Can I still download the image of it and where?

Comment: I dont believe you can downgrade once upgraded, but search google for the ios image file of the version you want and try the same steps of restoring.  I know some websites keep old ios image files but I dont have any links off-hand.

Comment: I want to move from iOS 5 beta to iOS 5 which is just released. It is not downgrade. it is update.

Comment: Oh, then download the ios5 GM from the dev center (1.5ish gig file) and do the same restore.

Comment: The iOS 5.0 GM isn't available from the developer.apple.com any more - short of downloading from an unofficial site, is there any other way to get hold of the OS image?

Comment: @gmaclachlan Actually, ill have to check again, i thought it was up there on dev.apple, hmmm.